# Cloud Endpoint Gradle Dependencies

Tags: java, android, gradle, google-cloud-endpoints

I was watching a video from Developers.Google on how to add an Endpoint database.

The endpoint is working because when I visit my developers console and use the Api in the browser is working fine. So my Java code is working. My problem is being when gradle tries to synchronize.

Here's is what I have.

```
compile('com.gabilheri.robot.cloud:robotAPI:v1-1.17.0-rc-SNAPSHOT') {
   exclude(group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient')
}

compile('com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.17.0-rc') {
    exclude(group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android')
    exclude(group: 'org.apache.httcomponents', module: 'httpclient')
}
```

And here is what the guy in the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Sp4Lr3Qmcw) has:

```
compile('com.google.todotxt.backend:taskApi:v1-1.17.0-rc-SNAPSHOT') {
   exclude(group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient')
}

compile('com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.17.0-rc') {
    exclude(group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android')
    exclude(group: 'org.apache.httcomponents', module: 'httpclient')
}
```

What I changed for me was the name of my package and API but i'm getting and sync error from
Gradle.

In the video it seems that android-studio auto completed for him. But My Android Studio is not getting any code completion for Gradle AT ALL. Using Android-Studio 0.54 on Mac OSX.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the maven repositories to your gradle file?

Example:

```
respositories{
    mavenLocal()
}
```

Comment: It worked!! Thanks!! After adding the repositories now the code is compiling! :)